# Firefox ubuntu - unable to access video player

Tags: flash, ubuntu, firefox

I installed firefox on ubuntu. I would like the selenium test to click on the play button in a video player. Unfortunately, the test fails everytime it tries to do so. I don't want to play the  video on the linux box. I just want the test to click on the play button inside the video. How do I install flash player on ubuntu box so that firefox can load flash players correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
Select APT in the download dropdown and run it

By default firefox will prompt you to activate flash on a site by site basis. If you are trying to do automated tests you may want to disable this which you can do by going to about:addons in the url bar and under the entry for flash, change the ask to activate setting to always active